# Catch Two Exceptions, One the Superclass of Another

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

I have a factory method that is parsing text and creating an Object. In this factory method, there is a section that reads until the end of a stream. There is another method that I have written that implements this part of the parser. Here is the code I'm using:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while (reader.ready()) {
            builder.append(reader.readLine());
        }
    } catch (EOFException e) {
                    // end method normally.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e; // end method with an exception.
    }
```

I want to treat the EOFException differently than the IOException, so I catch them in different `catch()` blocks. My question is: after an `EOFException` is thrown, will the `IOException` `catch()` block run? I suppose I could use a `boolean` that will be set in the EOFException area and tested in the IOException area, but this isn't as clean as I'd like it to be. Sorry I didn't describe that well, and thanks in advance.

Comment: If one exception is caught, the other's catching code will not run. You can put any necessary code in `finally { }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: after an EOFException is thrown, will the IOException catch() block run?

No it won't.

The runtime attempts to use the equivalent of `instanceof` to match the exception against the handlers' exceptions, in source code order.  The first exception match determines the handler that will be executed.  The exception is only handled once by the try-catch.

> I suppose I could use a boolean that will be set in the EOFException area and tested in the IOException area ...

That is not necessary.  (And it wouldn't work anyway.)

References:

- The Oracle Java Tutorial - ["The catch block"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)
- The Java Language Specification - [14.20.1. Execution of try-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.1)

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't. At most one catch block will be executed for a given try -- no more.